# How to perform excel MATCHINDEX or lookups in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I basically need to find relevant row value from first-column i.e (type) for max values of each column in below Data frame.

Lets suppose this is df3 data frame shown below.

I need to find relevant "type" row values for all the max values of numeric columns.

for example: max(price) => 8,85,113 => corr_logx (this is the output I need to find for all the numeric variables)

```
type         price           Bedroom_3  Bedroom_4
corr_x       3,56,315    5,01,687    6,05,458 
corr_logx    8,85,113    2,27,955    1,28,834 
corr_expx    8,34,503    3,62,952    2,30,759 
corr_sqrtx   6,29,162    3,36,964    8,96,593 
corr_sqrex   7,79,030    8,54,539    6,07,960 

Output I need:

Variable transfrm_used
Price     corr_logx
Bedroom_3 corr_sqrex
Bedroom_4 corr_sqrtx
```

For this:
I created a list of numeric column names and used it as range in for-loop. This helps me to step in each column.

Within each column then I created another for loop which will step in each row to match with the max value of the column.

If value matches then it should result in relevant value from the first column/ column 0/ column name - type. Otherwise it should continue looking for the match.

```
cols_list = df3.columns.difference(['type'])
transfrm_used = []
variable = []

for col_name in cols_list:
    variable.append(col_name) # this gives the respective column name 
    print(variable)


    for rows in range(0,5):
        if df3[rows,col_name] == np.max(df3.col_name):  # works as Match
            transfrm_used.append(df3[rows,0])    
        else:
            continue

print('done')
```

I am looking for a result format where I can get both column names like price, Bedroom_3 etc. and its relevant value from type column like corr_logx.

In excel it is done by using MATCHINDEX and lookups. Here is the complete set of data frame and expected result

```
type        price       Bedroom_3   Bedroom_4
corr_x       3,56,315    5,01,687    6,05,458 
corr_logx    8,85,113    2,27,955    1,28,834 
corr_expx    8,34,503    3,62,952    2,30,759 
corr_sqrtx   6,29,162    3,36,964    8,96,593 
corr_sqrex   7,79,030    8,54,539    6,07,960 


            max_price   max_Bedroom_3   max_Bedroom_4
max_value:  8,85,113     8,54,539    8,96,593 


relevant_type: corr_logx    corr_sqrex  corr_sqrtx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure that there's only one instance of each max price, to find max of column, a .max() will do. Then, we can find the type of that row:

```
max_value = {}
relevant_type = {}
for col_name in cols_list:
    max_val = df[col_name].max()
    max_value[col_name] = max_val
    relevant_type[col_name] = df.loc[df[col_name] == max_val,'type']
```

Then, we can add these two dicts as rows at the bottom of the dataframe:

```
df3.append(max_value, ignore_index=True)
df3.append(relevant_type, ignore_index=True)
```

Or we can make a new dataframe:

```
combined_dict = {x: [max_value[x],relevant_type[x]] for x in max_value}
df = pd.DataFrame(combined_dict, index=['max value','relevant type'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and providing different options for it @Jim Eisenberg. It works perfectly.

Comment: Happy to help - if this suited what you needed, please do accept the answer :)

Comment: I already accepted (clicked on top arrow mark) but it doesn't show any change in count over there. Let me know if there is any other way to do it. I am new here :)

Comment: I'm also quite new - but welcome to Stack Overflow :) The up and down arrows are for upvoting and downvoting - I think you need a certain amount of "points" to do that. Underneath the arrows, there should be some sort of star symbol - clicking on that accepts the answer. (Incidentally, accepting answers gives you more points, so you will be able to upvote things).

Comment: Yea, there was a mark that I just clicked, thanks for letting me know :))